# SLES AutoYaST Script Validity Verification

Tags: linux, sles, autoyast

Does anyone here write their own customized AutoYaST scripts for building SLES servers?

I'm not talking about generating them with `yast2 autoyast`.

If so, have you found a way to verify the syntax?  `xmllint` is good as far as telling you that the XML syntax is valid, but with an upto date DTD, it can't tell you anything more, and the shipped DTDs are out-of-date.

I've opened a ticket with Novell on this, but who knows when and what I'll hear back.

Comment: AFAIK the "not up to date" DTDs are still the main problem. Even yast generates xml-code that does not pass the DTD-check.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own for SLES 9 a couple years back, but I just ran through a bunch of live tests where I was booting a virtual machine and pointing it at the autoyast.xml file.  Boot, load the file, find problem, fix it, boot again.  Worked like a charm when it was finished.

Answer (score 0):

I found another tool that I yet have to actually try out, I have no idea if it will work, but I'm going to make note of it here for future reference.

```
/usr/bin/jing -c /usr/share/YaST2/schema/autoyast/rnc/profile.rnc autoyast.xml
```